# Меняют ли состояние программы операции ветвления?

Tags: любой-язык, условия

Многие операции меняют состояние программы через присваивание, приведение и т.д.
Меняют ли состояние программы операции ветвления ([условные операторы](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)))? Или они просто переводят, в зависимости от некоторых условий, в одну из частей общего состояния?

Я так пониманию состояние программы это вся совокупность вычисляемых и/или используемых значений, потенциально изменчивых и/или постоянных в данный момент работающей программы. Могу конечно ошибаться.

Comment: Что такое "состояние программы" ? Дайте четкое определение. И да и нет. Зависит с какого бока глядеть. Да- потому что как ни крути меняется регистр процессора, который является частью состояния программы. Нет- потому что регистр процессора не является частью состояния программы.

Comment: @ReinRaus: я так пониманию состояние программы это вся совокупность вычисляемых и/или используемых значений, потенциально изменчивых и/или постоянных в данный момент работающей программы. Могу конечно ошибаться.

Comment: Не могу себе представить состояние программы без указателя на текущую выполняемую команду...

Comment: @Harry ну можно например в verilog или vhdl например и без указателя на текущую команду ))

Comment: imho меняют даже без учета регистра команд. ведь после них мы находимся в другой ветви программы, которая может кардинально по другому обрабатывать информацию, а если переход в эту ветвь бы не произошел то и изменения поведения не было бы. без точного определения термина "состояние программы" и на какой момент времени однозначно ответить на вопрос невозможно

Comment: @TimurVI вы хотите ещё ответов или привлекаете внимание к уже данным?

Comment: @Nick Volynkin: хочется правильный ответ выбрать. Какой больше наберет.

Comment: Кол-во голосов не указывает однозначно на правильность ответа. Вы бы лучше комментарий про состояние программы в тело вопроса внесли.

Comment: @TimurVI, на неконкретно поставленный вопрос не может быть правильного ответа.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Текст программы лучше всего представить себе в виде набора пересекающихся дорог, а состояние выполняющего эту программу процесса — как машину, едущую по этим дорогам.

При этом ветвлениям соответствуют развилки дорог, циклам — круговое движение, и т. д. Любая операция есть продвижение машины по дороге, ветвление — выбор одной из дорог на развилке и продвижение по выбранной дороге.

Таким образом, ветвление не есть состояние, это лишь свойство «дорожной сети», её форма. А вот прохождение программой ветвления, как и **любая другая операция**, изменяет положение машины на дороге, то есть, состояние программы.

Comment: В таком случае состояние программы не меняют никакие операторы или функции? А меняет только их выполнение? Т.е. мы отделяем программу от ее выполнения?

Comment: @Harry: Именно так. Оператор ветвления — это часть _текста программы_, он не является «активной» сущностью. _По-моему, так (с)_

Comment: Автор утверждает, что *Многие операции меняют состояние программы*. Т.е. получается, что операция - это выполнение текста программы. Тогда, по логике, ответ на вопрос *Меняют ли состояние программы операции ветвления* - положительный, раз речь идет об *операциях*. Я не с вами спорю. я скорее размышляю вслух... Т.е. ответ на вопрос ТС, если кратко - да, меняют. Так?

Comment: @Harry: Ну, мой ответ предлагает различать _операции_ и _выполнение операций_. Обычно можно себе позволить вольность речи не различать их, но в данном контексте различие важно. Фактически, нету понятия «состояние программы», есть «состояние процесса», то есть, пробега программы. И как только мы ввели различие, сразу же становится ясно, что **любая** операция изменяет состояние _процесса_.

Comment: @Harry: То есть, если объединить программу и процесс, то ответ «да». Но я бы не объединял.

Comment: @VladD: про разделение текста программы и процесса очень интересно. Не различал так тонко когда задавал вопрос.

Answer (score 14):

Не могу себе представить состояние программы без указателя на текущую выполняемую команду...

Поэтому считаю, что любая операция ветвления меняет состояние программы. Впрочем, как любая операция вообще - ибо состояние программы в самом начале выполнения и в самом ее конце вряд ли кто-то назовет идентичными, правда? :)

Answer (score 7):

Предположим, у нас программа на условном императивном языке без многопоточности. Нам нужно прервать выполнение программы, и выгрузить ее текущее *состояние* в файл, чтобы потом можно было загрузить и продолжить с точки остановки. Что нам нужно выгрузить:

1. Код (в принципе, он может подгружаться из исполняемого файла, но бывают нюансы типа самораспаковывающихся/самомодифицирующихся программ)
2. Глобальные переменные
3. Стек (стек вызовов и стек локальных переменных функций до текущей выполняемой функции включительно)
4. Адрес/номер строки выполняемой команды на момент создания "снимка" состояния.

Это и есть все, что описывает текущее состояние нашей программы. Если что-то из этого "забыть" выгрузить/загрузить, то просто не получится вернуть программу в требуемое состояние.

Таким образом любая команда (в том числе `nop` в ассемблере или `pass` в Python) меняют как минимум адрес/номер текущей выполняемой команды, а значит меняют состояние программы. Операции ветвления тут ничем особенным не выделяются.

Answer (score 6):

Может зависеть от того, что вы понимаете под состоянием программы. По моему состояние программы, это, как и у *конечного автомата*, то, что определяет дальнейшее поведение программы. А любая операция ветвления меняет дальнейшее поведение программы и следовательно ее состояние.

Answer (score 6):

Как тут справедливо заметили, сложность ответа на этот вопрос возникает из-за неопределенности наших терминов. Попробуем рассуждать с позиции [функционального программирования](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) (опять же, в статье по ссылке есть спорные моменты). На входе и выходе любой программы есть объект.

Если мы определим термин "состояние программы" как совокупность всех возможных состояний "программы" в классическом понимании, то это состояние неизменно и независимо от любых детерминированных операторов в "программе". Поведение программы будет предопределено, будь в качестве входного объекта хоть координаты всех атомов во Вселенной.

Однако мы можем расширить наше понятие "программы" на алгоритмы, модифицирующиеся по действительно случайному закону.

Тут уже начинается философия. Можно ли генетические алгоритмы природы, относящиеся к последнему случаю, считать "программой"? Мы сами - программа?

Если совсем формально:

Програ́мма — термин, в переводе означающий «предписание» (Wiki).
К примеру, описания схем на уже упомянутых здесь vhdl и verilog - это программы,
содержащие условные операторы, но не содержащие программного счетчика.

В общем случае ни программный счетчик, ни переменные не являются неотъемлемой частью программы.

Так что мой ответ - нет.